# Channel Entries - Advanced Entry Id Filters

Tags: channel-entries

When using the entry_id param in `{exp:channel:entries}`, is it possible to do some advanced conditions like

entry_id="(not 58) AND 99|100|101"

Basically, what I was looking for is if you can use AND, OR and NOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with this tag.

Comment: Ok, I guess I can't use {exp:channel:entries} then

Answer (score 1):

You can probably accomplish what you're seeking to do by using the [**Channel Query**](https://github.com/expressodev/channel_query) plugin. It has all of the features of `{exp:channel:entries}`, with the flexibility of the Query module.

```
{exp:channel_query 
    sql="SELECT entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE /* your custom query here */"
}
    <!-- all channel entries variables can be used here -->
{/exp:channel_query}
```

Comment: Nice add-on! I need to check if this is compatible with the latest ExpressionEngine version though.

Comment: The Channel Query plugin works fine for me with EE 2.7.2